# Count query not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a custom query in codeigniter to count results.

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post WHERE MATCH (title, description)     AGAINST ('+$search_string*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)", NULL, TRUE);
```

But this is generating only 1 rows, but if i run this query in phpmyadmin then it shows correct results. What is the wrong I am doing?

Comment: What is the + mark before $search_string ?

Comment: To match any word that has $search_string

Comment: Yes, it's correct that it returns only 1 row and in that row you will find the value that contains the number of posts that match your query.

Comment: You can use LIKE instead of AGAINST, '%$search_string%'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $q = $this -> db -> query($your_custom_query);
 return $q -> num_rows();
```

This should work for  you, but you have to replace **COUNT(*) by any field in the table or ***, i would suggest a field. like say .. title.

You query does not work because $this->db->query resturns and object which needs to be converted to an array, by someting like `foreach ($q->result() as $row) {}` ..

**you may also try** `return $this -> db -> query($your_custom_query)->result();`

Comment: did you replace the COUNT(*) with a fields name?

Comment: Thanks! (Y) . This is working! That is what i was wondering how to get count value in CI. I just used return $query->result() and it is working....... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
$query =  $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCounnt FROM post WHERE 
MATCH (title, description) 
AGAINST ('+$search_string*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)", NULL, TRUE);

$result = $query->row();

return $result->totalCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how count is done using CI active record class

```
    $this->db->where('name', $name);
    $this->db->where('id !=', $artist_id);
    $this->db->from('artists');

    return $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Comment: I am using here my custom query.

Comment: I have userd @Archer solution. It is ok now... Anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is extra parameters in `query()`...[docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) here

however going thorugh `but if i run this query in phpmyadmin then it shows correct results`..
you can try pritning the last query that was made just to check if it is correct or not...you can do that by..

```
 $test=$this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post WHERE MATCH (title, description)     AGAINST ('+$search_string*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"); //no need of other parameters
 echo $this->db->last_query();exit;
```

and after query is made you have to generate result...

in yourcase that would be..

```
  return $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post WHERE MATCH (title, description)     AGAINST ('+$search_string*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")->row_array();
```

[ways](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) for generating result